# Showing open subsets and closed subsets of a variety are also varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know this question has been asked before but the definition of variety I am using is not that it is a zero set of some family of polynomials. The definition I am using is

> A variety is a topological space $X$ together with a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X$ (we view $\mathcal{O}_X$ as a subsheaf of $\mathcal{C}_X$, the sheaf of continuous functions on $X$ with values in $\mathbb{k}$), that satisfy the following properties.
>
> (1) $X$ is quasicompact
>
> (2) Every point $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U_x$ such that $(U_x,{\mathcal{O}_{X}|}_{U_{x}})\cong (V,\mathcal{O}_V)$, where $V$ is an open subset of an affine variety $U$ and $\mathcal{O}_{V}=\mathcal{O}_{U}|_{V}$

Note that this was something which was stated in lectures and was left as an exercise. The actual exercise was show that a closed subvariety is indeed a variety, apparently open subvarieties are apparently also varieties.

I am interpreting this as showing any closed (open) subset of a variety is a variety, since if it is a subvariety...isn't it already a variety. Anyway, if someone could explain where my understanding has gone wrong and perhaps show that a closed (or open) subvariety of a variety is indeed a variety and leave the other one as an exercise that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

A variety $X$ is Noetherian (exercise). Thus, every subset of $X$ is quasi-compact. Now let $W$ be a closed irreducible subset of $X$ and let $\mathcal{O}_W(V)$ be the set of all functions $f\colon V\to k$ such that if $x\in V$ then there is a neighbourhood $U_x\subseteq X$ of $x$ and a $g\in\mathcal{O}_X(U_x)$ such that $g= f\mid_{U_x\cap V}$. Can you show that $(V,\mathcal{O}_W(V))$ is a variety?

Now suppose that $Y$ is an open subset of $X$. Can you show that $Y$ can be given the structure of a variety? (we know its quasi-compact, since $X$ is Noetherian)